# Adwords traffic shows as 'not set' in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, google-ads, ppc

In Google Analytics if I go to **Traffic sources > Search > Paid** all I get is "not set".

Instead of the usual list of keywords that people have used to find the ad, this makes it really difficult to understand whats going on in the campaign..

I've gone into Adwords and turned on auto tagging but still have the same problem

Any idea how I can fix this so under the Paid tab I get the phrases people have used to find my ad in PPC?

Comment: I have the same problem but my site isn't using Google Adwords, just Analytics...

Comment: @Rach welcome to stack exchange! In the future, use the answer feature only if you actually have an answer to the question, and leave a comment or ask a different question if you don't have an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/static.py?hl=en&selected=a6_a6h3_a6h3t3&page=troubleshooter.cs&ctx=gatsc_a6_a6h3_a6h3t3_72716&problem=gatsc)

Advertisers will see an AdWords keyword, Ad Group, or Campaign shown as (not set) entries when Analytics is not able to identify that particular dimension. There are several possible causes:

- Auto-tagging is on but cost data is not applied (learn more)
- There is a redirect in the URL
- The gclid parameter is altered or dropped from the ad
- Auto and manual tagging are being used at the same time
- Manually tagged URLs are missing a value

Occasionally, information related to the click can be lost even if your URL has been properly appended with Google AdWords auto-tagging. If none of the causes above match up to your situation, you may wish to disable auto-tagging and instead use the URL Builder to tag your destination URLs.

Comment: if im using event click tracking analytics like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) would this be conflicting ? I cant see how it would be as im trying to click inbound links, where as i have these to setup internal linking